# Clear a kml that was added to google earth using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I have added a kml to google earth by use of button with javascript. How can I delete that kml or clear all kml's by use of another button?  thanks

Comment: I believe I'm trying to do something similar. I've been trying to remove a folder from the kml when a link is clicked in the balloon. See my answer below for the closest I've gotten.

Answer (score 3):

To remove all the features you can use the following method. It presumes that 'ge' references your plug-in object.

```
function RemoveAllFeatures()
{
  var features = ge.getFeatures();
  while (features.getLastChild() != null)
  {
    features.removeChild(features.getLastChild());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you added a KML file? I guess you did this by adding a "network link" using functions like

```
var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('ID_MyNetworkLink');
var link = ge.createLink('MyHREF');
link.setHref('http://bla.bla.bla.kml');
networkLink.setLink(link);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

So your "file" is a child of the whole KML tree with id "ID_MyNetworkLink". You can remove it by

```
ge.getFeatures().removeChild(ge.getElementById('ID_MyNetworkLink'));
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Though not quite what you are likely looking for you can have a NetworkLink that loads kml with a NetworkLinkController change things. Check out the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/updates.html).